# Is It Possible to display Employee details in Treeview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I need help on treeview control. I am using treeview control in my aspx page and binding data from database using store procedure. My output is fine but i have an issue to show employee details side of treeview. I mean if an user clicks an node or value in treeview control i need to display details of selected value in treeview control. Is it possible to create a profile table side of treeview..Please help me to solve the issue.

Below is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Username"] == null)
    {
        Session["Msg"] = "Your session has expired. please login again";
        Response.Redirect("../Account/login.aspx");
        //.........
        return;
    }


private void GetTreeViewItems()
{
    try
    {
       string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_GetEmployee", con);    
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ds.Relations.Add("ChildRows", ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["ManagerId"]);
        foreach (DataRow level1DataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(level1DataRow["ManagerId"].ToString()))
            {
                TreeNode parentTreeNode = new TreeNode();
                parentTreeNode.Text = level1DataRow["FirstName"].ToString();
              // parentTreeNode.Text = level1DataRow["Designation"].ToString();
                parentTreeNode.Value = level1DataRow["id"].ToString();

                GetChildRows(level1DataRow, parentTreeNode);
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentTreeNode);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void GetChildRows(DataRow dataRow, TreeNode treeNode)
{
    DataRow[] childRows = dataRow.GetChildRows("ChildRows");
    foreach (DataRow childRow in childRows)
    {
        TreeNode childTreeNode = new TreeNode();
        childTreeNode.Text = childRow["FirstName"].ToString();
      // childTreeNode.Text = childRow["Designation"].ToString();
        childTreeNode.Value = childRow["id"].ToString();
        treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(childTreeNode);
        if (childRow.GetChildRows("ChildRows").Length > 0)
        {
            GetChildRows(childRow, childTreeNode);
        }
    }
}
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{

}


protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108368/windows-form-treeview-with-dynamic-child/29108838#29108838

Comment: Thank You Sayka for suggestion. But i am looking like... If You consider computer where you ill find My Documents,My Pictures and etc on left side of Screen.. when click My Document you gonna see data present in My document beside of my document. Thus how i am looking...

Comment: Thats treeview with icons.

Comment: That i've done when schooling.

Comment: Screenshot -> http://www.sayka.in/imgs/treeview.png

Comment: was an sqlite + msSql like application for project in school

Comment: Actually I seen your screenshot..I am unable to upload screenshot here..Consider in your screenshot if user clicks emp id then data related to emp id should be displayed side of that treeview..

Comment: I see no screenshots

Comment: Actually I seen your screenshot..I am unable to upload screenshot here..Consider in your screenshot if user clicks emp id then data related to emp id should be displayed side of that treeview..

Comment: Thats what the primary thing done by answer to the link i provided at the first comment. Why you think it wont help? It reference using a employee name. All you have to do is to change to Emp ID.

Comment: Sorry Sayka i troubing you..once see my code and let me know how can i do it.

Comment: No troubles in Stackoverflow. If any answer helps you,  and you upvote, then there is a deal..

Comment: Sure...Please help me in solving the issue...

Comment: So now can u see the parent nodes?

Comment: How to display here..I dont have acess to show as a image

Comment: When you edit your question, you can see an image icon on top

Comment: I need to get 10 reputation then only i can upload image

Comment: Is there a property called **Value** for a TreeNode()

Comment: yes..Value is used has Id in my employee table.

Comment: There is no Value property in winforms. You're using aspx right. Now i see

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Is it that you dont see anything onLoad, or see only parent nodes, or child nodes are not accessible....???

Comment: I can see all the data in treeview control parent node child node..when i click child node i need to see details of child node on the right side of treeview..I am using table which contains all details of child node..in treeview control i am just considering ManagerId and EmployeeID..Whenever a child node is selected it should display Remaininng columns

Comment: I donno anything in asp but still i tried to make a webforms application by adding new project. I've laughed out loud looking at conjuring the first time but scared to death looking at the weird behaviour of asp when i try to do something. My father hav already told me not to play with asp, and i wil never do it again. Sorry.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[windows form treeview with dynamic child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108368/windows-form-treeview-with-dynamic-child/29108838#29108838)

The answer here will give you an idea how to implement the treeView for employees